# Changing between multiple bands of PID values

Tags: pid-controller

I have to control the temperature of an oven from room temperature to around 600degC. To do so I divide the temperature range into multiple bands eg 0-200, 200-400, 400-600 etc. Each range has a set of PID values, since I have discovered by experiment that one set is not sufficiently accurate. The question is whether I use the target temperature to determine the PID values to use, or whether I use the actual temperature to switch between bands as temperature increases. How is it normally done?

Comment: I can't imagine that changing thermal capacity with temperature is the cause of needing different values, I'd guess that the heat loss as f(T) changes the effective heater power, and the different ratio of radiation transfer to convection/conductivity changes time constants. You don't say what is inadequate about the 'wrong' set of coefficients, presumably overshoots? If the transition from cold to target is an uncontrolled heating slew, then final temperature may be all you need. If you need control at intermediate temperatures, thne the current temperature sounds the right one to use.

Comment: oh, good question! I don't know the system, but I guess an oven is not overly sensitive to sudden jumps in control strategy, so a hard switchover would work. However, it *does* sound like you'd basically want to put another layer of control on top: scenario: letting the oven cool down *controlledly* from 500 to 100 °C. Things cool down from 401 °C to 399 °C, the PID parameters switch, which leads to the lower-band PID to fire up the oven, heating it with a dead-time between heating and measurement that suffices to jump to 403 °C, so you start oscillating and never reach 100 °C; on the

Comment: other hand, the parameters at 100 °C aren't appropriate for 490 °C, as your initial problem states. The solution would quite possibly be to refine your simple PID: I guess its input is temperature, but what the factor in front of the differential control contribution be proportional to the inside/outside temperature difference square (to kind of model the heat flow speed)?

Comment: The actual temperature should be used for selecting the gain-set. The gains are usually designed based on the plant (current) operating point; not the target point. Also, consider a case where the *final* target is not known in real time; e.g a human turning the set-point dials frequently; in such cases, the current operating point is known, and can be used for gain selection; but the unknown target can't be used.